# Data model for CosmosDB SQL API for limited event registration

Tags: transactions, azure-cosmosdb, relationship, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to create a website that allows some persons to create events (title, date, time, etc.) and others to register for and also deregister from those events. The creator of the event can specify the maximum number of attendees (e.g. maximum 10 persons for a BBQ) (most of the time between 10 and 500 persons).

I also have some requirements (from "must have" to "nice to have"):

- Transactional safety: It shouldn't be possible that the maximum number of attendees is exceeded
- Allow increasing or decreasing maximum number of attendees (as long as `max number of attendees > current number of attendees`)
- Querying current number of attendees should be cheap (e.g. "4/10 attendees")
- Querying events per user should be cheap (e.g. User U registered for Event E1, E2, and E3)
- Avoid storing redundant data

I decided to give CosmosDB and its SQL API a try. I set up an "Event" container to store events in. Now I'm thinking about storing event registrations where I see the following possibilities, all with their advantages and disadvantages:

1. Include registrations within the event itself, e.g.

   ```json
   {
       "id": "b21e28e9-61c6-454a-8438-4a75e74a854b",
       "title": "BBQ",
       "date": "2022-05-17",
       "time": "17:00",
       "maxAttendees": 10,
       "attendeeIds": [
           "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357",
           "1ad88926-037d-4bf0-b50c-b380f3f5fa9f",
       ]
   }
   ```

   - Advantages

     - Simplicity
     - Registration considering `maxAttendees` can be made transactional using the patch and conditional update (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update)
   - Disadvantages

     - Deregistration is only possible using the array index of `attendeeIds` (again using the patch and conditional update to ensure that the index points to the correct item this might work, but it feels a bit dirty)
2. Store registration *events* within the event itself (similar to an event store), e.g.

   ```json
   {
       "id": "b21e28e9-61c6-454a-8438-4a75e74a854b",
       "title": "BBQ",
       "date": "2022-05-17",
       "time": "17:00",
       "maxAttendees": 10,
       "attendanceEvents": [
           { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "register" },
           { "userId": "1ad88926-037d-4bf0-b50c-b380f3f5fa9f", "type": "register" },
           { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "deregister" },
           { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "register" }
       ]
   }
   ```

   - Advantages

     - Deregistration is easier because it's just another added operation
   - Disadvantages

     - Not sure how we would allow or deny registering a user because to get the current number of attendees we would need to consider all `attendanceEvents`. Even when additionally storing the current number of attendees, we would need to ensure that two contiguous "register" events are only counted as one.
3. Store registrations in another container (e.g. "EventRegistrations") (as with typical SQL DBs):

   - Event

     ```json
     {
         "id": "b21e28e9-61c6-454a-8438-4a75e74a854b",
         "title": "BBQ",
         "date": "2022-05-17",
         "time": "17:00",
         "maxAttendees": 10,
         "currentAttendees": 3 // Optional, simplifies displaying available slots
     }
     ```
   - Registration

     ```json
     {
         "id": "6b5beddc-24be-4ddf-9171-7a680093870f", // optionally eventId and userId concatenated
         "eventId": "b21e28e9-61c6-454a-8438-4a75e74a854b",
         "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357"
     }
     ```
   - Advantages

     - Adding and removing registrations is easy
     - Querying the events per user is easier
   - Disadvantages

     - Adding a registration can't be made transactional because I can't read `maxAttendees` and write the registration in one go (right?)

Can anyone think of a way to mitigate the disadvantages of the above approaches? Or can anyone think of a totally different approach?

Comment: The first thing that pops up in my mind is to maybe think about the pattern: Command/Query. This means you create two models (ReadModel, WriteModel), one is for the writing which contains all the data you need, and editing it should be very easy. 

When you save the WriteModel, you can make a distilled version called the ReadModel and save it which will be prepared for rapid use. High index, flat structure. This will increase the performance very much.

Comment: So, you don't really have to worry about the structure but rather the ease of use. And the ReadModel is made for the retrieving of the data.

Comment: Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that pops up in my mind is to maybe think about the pattern: `Command/Query`. This means you create two models (`ReadModel`, `WriteModel`), one is for the writing which contains all the data you need, and editing it should be very easy.

When you save the `WriteModel`, you can make a distilled version called the `ReadModel` and save it which will be prepared for rapid use. High index, flat structure. This will increase the performance very much.

Something like:

`WriteModel`:

```json
{
    "id": "b21e28e9-61c6-454a-8438-4a75e74a854b",
    "title": "BBQ",
    "date": "2022-05-17",
    "time": "17:00",
    "maxAttendees": 10,
    "attendanceEvents": [
        { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "register" },
        { "userId": "1ad88926-037d-4bf0-b50c-b380f3f5fa9f", "type": "register" },
        { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "deregister" },
        { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "register" }
    ]
}
```

In the model (In my case C#) you can make all the validation

```cs
public class EventModel
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int MaxAttendees {get;set;}
    public List<EventUserModel> EventUsers {get; private set;}
    
    public void AddUser(string id, string type)
    {
        if (this.EventUsers.Count >= this.MaxAttendees) {
            return;
        }
        
        this.EventUsers.Add(new EventUserModel() { Id = id, Type =type });
    }
}

public class EventUserModel {
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

And the `ReadModel` will look like this:

```cs
public class EventReadModel
{
    private int _currentAttendees;
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int MaxAttendees {get;set;}
    public int CurrentAttendees
    {
        get => this._currentAttendees;
        set => _currentAttendees = this.EventUsers.Count;
    }
    public List<EventUserReadModel> EventUsers {get; set;}
}

public class EventUserReadModel {
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

The `ReadModel` will be then used to query the data (Select) and will be updated every time you update the Model.

```json
{
    "id": "b21e28e9-61c6-454a-8438-4a75e74a854b",
    "title": "BBQ",
    "date": "2022-05-17",
    "time": "17:00",
    "maxAttendees": 10,
    "currentAttendees": 3,
    "attendanceEvents": [
        { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "register", "firstName": ... },
        { "userId": "1ad88926-037d-4bf0-b50c-b380f3f5fa9f", "type": "register", "firstName": ... },
        { "userId": "5b5a6b75-4b4e-4824-8a7b-c1d9c7783357", "type": "deregister", "firstName": ... }
    ]
}
```

I hope that answers your question. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you.
But creating the event and registering for an event is an asynchronous process - it's done by different users. So for a specific event where there is only one more slot left, how can I guarantee that only one user gets that slot, despite another users booking that slot at the exact same time?

Comment: Well, the easiest way for this challenge is to add a lock from the programming language itself. Almost all languages offer such functionality to prevent the multiple access of the piece of code simultaneously. See, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: I am not pretty sure that this problem is a database problem. It is rather a use case that can be solved with the code. CosmosDB Triggers post-edit however might also solve the problem which is something I don't recommend due to many future issues and bad user experience.

Comment: But typical databases are exactly made for handling transactions and putting locks around operations. Imagine having multiple instances of a web server because of scaling out. I can't use application locks in this case. This must be done within the database.

Comment: Well, CosmosDb is NoSql Database that works differently than the traditional database. But there is a solution to your problem which is the eTag. This will be updated after every edit. See: https://www.codit.eu/blog/catering-for-azure-cosmos-db-optimistic-concurrency/

Comment: You can provide the etag from the document you want to save as a request option `var requestOptions = new ItemRequestOptions { IfMatchEtag = dbData.Resource._etag };` and this will be then compared to the one already saved in the document which will change every save. However, deleting might be an issue.

Comment: For the delete problem, you can separate the insert/update instead of using upsert. This will then throw an exception when you use update and if the document does not exist.

Comment: see `AccessCondition` https://codeopinion.com/documentdb-optimistic-concurrency/

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you. Using the ETag I can verify that noone registered in the meantime. If the ETag doesn't match, I just have to fetch the event again and retry.